# How to prevent variables from leaking in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

This is my JavaScript code that I have for 1 js file for each page in my website. it is for a task manager and it saves and gets and displays the data in the webpage however the info that is saved seems to leak over to the other js files.

This is my code how do I possibly contain these variable so that they don't leak over and the tasks show over to another webpage?
website: https://dailytaskmanager-ss.netlify.app/

```
var myObj= { 
    textSelect: function(){
        document.getElementById('description').select();
    },

    hide: function() {
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("show").style.display = "inline-block";

},
    show:function(){

    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('myDate').valueAsDate = new Date();
    },
    removeTask: function () {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    var myTasks = returnToDo();
    myTasks.splice(id, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(myTasks));
    document.getElementById('myTasks').innerHTML = '';
    showMyTasks();
    console.log('delete');

}
};
function returnToDo(){
    var myTasks = [];
    var myTasksTemp = localStorage.getItem('myData');
    if(myTasksTemp != null){
        myTasks = JSON.parse(myTasksTemp);
    }
    return myTasks;
}
function Task(){
    this.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    this.subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    this.date = document.getElementById('myDate').value;
    this.describe = document.getElementById('description').value;
}
function newTask(x,y,z,o){
    document.getElementById('myTasks').innerHTML +=
        '<div class="col l3 m4 s12 animated zoomIn"> <h4>'+z+  ':</h1>'+
        '<p>'+y+'</p>' +
        '<p>By: '+x+'</p>' +
        '<p>Due: ' +o +'</p>'+
        '<div class="btn red" >Delete</div>'+
    '</div>'
}
function showMyTasks(){
    var myTasks = returnToDo();
    document.getElementById('myTasks').innerHTML = '';
    for(var i=0;i<myTasks.length;i++){
        newTask(
            myTasks[i].name,
            myTasks[i].describe,
            myTasks[i].subject,
            myTasks[i].date
        );
    }
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
    for (var j = 0; j < button.length; j++) {
        button[j].addEventListener('click', myObj.removeTask);
        console.log(button[j].addEventListener('click', myObj.removeTask));

    }
}
function submitInfo(){
    var myTasks = returnToDo();
    myTasks.push(new Task);
    localStorage.setItem('myData',JSON.stringify(myTasks));
    showMyTasks();
    myObj.hide();
}
showMyTasks();
```

Comment: "They leak over to another page?" You are running the same code on each page? You are saving them to local storage. You expect each page to have a separate local storage? That is not how local storage works. You need to rethink how you save your keys.

Comment: ahh yes also true, I didn't take that into account I created the code for one page initially and thought it would just work across

Answer (score 1):

> so that they don't leak over and the tasks show over to another webpage?

JavaScript programs (in the context of a `<script>` element) only exist inside the page the element appears in, so this won't happen.

> the info that is saved seems to leak over to the other js files.

To avoid variables declared in a `<script>` element conflicting with variables of the same name in another `<script>` element on the same page: **Don't use globals.**

Either (in my order of preference):

1. Use `<script type="module"` to make your script a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)
2. Wrap your script in a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and use `const` or `let` instead of `var`
3. Wrap your code in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Also avoid [implicit globals](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-implicit-globals). It is worth running your script in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which turns them into errors to make them easier to detect. Modules automatically run in strict mode.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand better any way i could possibly get your help changing the code to work?

Comment: This is not the OPs issue. The OP is using localstorage and expected the storage was unique to each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the TODO list and want it to be done on different pages you can use the same basic code, you just need to initialize it so that the key you are saving is unique to that TODO list. So you can just use a variable and have your script use that variable

```
<script>
  const todoPage = 'media';
</script>
<script src="yourTodoCode.js"></script>
```

and in your code you can use the variable when you read the storage

```js
// reading it
var myTasksTemp = localStorage.getItem(todoPage);
// and saving it
localStorage.setItem(todoPage, JSON.stringify(myTasks));
```

Personally I would be writing a class and avoid globals altogether.